# How can I monitor updates in Julia and all Julia packages?

Tags: julia

Is there an easy way to monitor commits and development of julia and all julia packages? I am aware of https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commits/master

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you watch the https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia repo, with appropriate GitHub settings, you will get emails for commits, pull-requests, issues, comments, etc. Packages are harder. You can similarly watch them if they're hosted on GitHub, but there are always new packages and you won't get updates about those. If you watch the https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl repo, however, you will get notifications about all the changes there, so you'll at least get some kind of heads up about newly registered packages.

Comment: The only thing I miss in Julia's ecosystem is a classical mailing list (not Google Groups).

Comment: [Octave](https://mailman.cae.wisc.edu/listinfo/octave-maintainers), [Boost C++](http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/boost), etc.

Comment: That appears to be just an alternative hosted mailing list service.